# RTL8188RU usb wireless card issue

Tags: wireless, usb

I bought a usb wireless card with RTL8188RU chipset.
And I use it with Ubuntu 12.04.3.
But it only can scan SSIDs. The connection is always failed.

Then I found that build-in driver rtl8192cu is buggy from google.
So I install official Realtek driver 4.0.2_9000 successfully.
Also add rtl8192cu to blacklist and add 8192cu to /etc/modules

But the problem is still the same.
There are some errors in dmesg.

```
[32174.031125] link to new AP
[32174.328532] link_timer_hdl: auth timeout and try again
[32174.631246] link_timer_hdl: auth timeout and try again
[32174.934012] link_timer_hdl: auth timeout and try again
[32175.236757] link_timer_hdl: auth timeout and try again
[32175.539467] report_join_res(-1)
```

These errors shows even the wifi is open without password.

Information from lsusb.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:817f Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Anyone could help? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device: lsusb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use kernel backports.
I was messing around with this driver with kubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 alpha one year ago.
Now with the current kernel in 13.10 the device works!

Comment: After I install 13.10 kernel by "sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy". It works great! Thanks.

Comment: Please set my answer as solution . Nice to hear it works.